# Pass a list as an argument to timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a dataframe (df_logs) in pandas as following:

```
name phone_number call_duration
Ana  4455533422    38
Mark 4452341115    300
Susan 33489982     120
```

The call_duration column is expressed in seconds and i would like to convert all values in this column to minutes.

To do this i wanted to use the timedelta object however i don't know how to pass a list of values instead of one given amount of seconds.

Instead of this:

```
time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds = 300))
```

I tried to pass without success each value in my 'call_duration' column like this:

```
df_logs = df_logs['call_duration'].values.astype(int)

time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds = [i for i in df_logs]))

time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds = *df_logs))
```

I would like to know how to convert my 'call_duration' from seconds to minutes.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your desired output data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [77]: df['new'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.call_duration, unit='s')

In [78]: df
Out[78]:
    name  phone_number  call_duration      new
0    Ana    4455533422             38 00:00:38
1   Mark    4452341115            300 00:05:00
2  Susan      33489982            120 00:02:00

In [79]: df.dtypes
Out[79]:
name                      object
phone_number               int64
call_duration              int64
new              timedelta64[ns]   # <----
dtype: object
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [93]: df['new'] = (df.call_duration/60).round().astype(int)

In [94]: df
Out[94]:
    name  phone_number  call_duration  new
0    Ana    4455533422             38    1
1   Mark    4452341115            300    5
2  Susan      33489982            120    2
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
In [109]: df
Out[109]:
    name  phone_number  call_duration
0    Ana    4455533422             38
1   Mark    4452341115            300
2  Susan      33489982            120
3    Max     123456789            564

In [110]: df['new'] = np.ceil(df.call_duration/60).astype(int)

In [111]: df
Out[111]:
    name  phone_number  call_duration  new
0    Ana    4455533422             38    1
1   Mark    4452341115            300    5
2  Susan      33489982            120    2
3    Max     123456789            564   10
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to round this numbers with round() method? Ex. if any number of seconds round to 1 minute. Output: 38 seconds = 1, 05:10 = 6...etc

Comment: @Ana, what `dtype` do you want to have in the resulting DF - `timedelta`, `float`, `int`?

Comment: Ideally an int i just want to have round up number of minutes so i can multiply them by a call rate. Thank you

Comment: @Ana, please see UPDATE... PS now you see why i asked you to post your desired data set in the comment.. ;-)

Comment: Yes thank you so much sorry not being too accurate. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but is there a way to indicate how to round uo the numbers. Example, now if in my table i have 564 seconds in minutes that's 09:04 which rounds up to 9 but i would like that it always rounds to the highest number so even if a minute is just over one second it will rounded to the next minute. If is 9:04 would need to round to 10

Comment: Perfect! No more questions now :). Thanks